# Getting foreign key with maximum occurrences

Tags: mysql, database

I have following following tables.

**user**
[image]

**option**
[image]

**question**
[image]

**answer**
[image]

I want to fetch the following records

1. Number of answers grouped by user
2. Most answered option grouped by user

I tried using following query

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.email,
    COUNT(a.question_id) as number_of_answers
FROM
    user u
LEFT JOIN
    answer a ON (a.user_id = u.id)
GROUP BY
    u.id;
```

Which gives me following result

[image]

I now want to fetch most used option per user, with reference to above image, I am expecting the following result

```
-----------------------
user_id  |   option_id
-----------------------
1        |   null
2        |   3
3        |   null
-----------------------
```

how to go about it?

**UPDATE:**

This query gives me the closest result,

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.email,
    COUNT(a.question_id) as number_of_answers,
    (SELECT a2.option_id FROM answer a2 WHERE a2.user_id = u.id GROUP BY a2.option_id ORDER BY COUNT(a2.option_id) DESC LIMIT 1) as option_id
FROM
    user u
LEFT JOIN
    answer a ON (a.user_id = u.id)
GROUP BY
    u.id;
```

The issue now is it does not order option_id as I expect, I want to get last occurrence of option_id if there are same number of maximum occurrences, with reference to content in below image.

[image]

It gives me the following result

```
+-----------+-----------+
| option_id | occurence |
+-----------+-----------+
|         5 |         2 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Whereas I expect the following

```
+-----------+-----------+
| option_id | occurence |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 |         2 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

The reason being, option_id is the last recorded option. any hint on what I am missing here?

Comment: Try to order your subselect by `COUNT(a2.option_id) DESC, MAX(a2.id) DESC`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, max(p.opt_count) occurances , p.option_id from user u 
JOIN (
  SELECT u.id, count(a.question_id) qc, a.option_id, count(a.option_id) opt_count 
  FROM user u
  LEFT JOIN answer a on u.id=a.user_id 
      GROUP by u.id, a.question_id, a.option_id  
 ) as p 
 ON u.id=p.id group by u.id ;
```

Comment: This gives me wrong result, it returns null for user with id 1 and 3 and option_id 1 for user with id 2, which is incorrect.

Comment: The query returns 4 columns, the third column is the 'occurrence' which is three and the fourth column is the option_id which is 1. giving result that option_id 1 was the highest with 3 occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it step by step using temporary tables:

```sql
-- get counts for each user and option
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_selected_options;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_selected_options
    SELECT a.user_id, a.option_id, COUNT(a.option_id) AS numSelected
    FROM answer a
    GROUP BY a.user_id, a.option_id
;
select * from tmp_selected_options;

-- get the max number an option was selected for each user
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_max_selected;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_max_selected
    SELECT so.user_id, MAX(so.numSelected) AS maxSelected
    FROM tmp_selected_options so
    GROUP BY so.user_id
;
select * from tmp_max_selected;

-- get otions that were selected most for each user
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_most_selected_otions;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_most_selected_otions
    SELECT so.user_id, so.option_id
    FROM tmp_max_selected ms
    JOIN tmp_selected_options so
        ON  so.user_id = ms.user_id
        AND so.numSelected = ms.maxSelected
;
select * from tmp_most_selected_otions;

-- get least option-id of most selected options for each user
SELECT u.id AS user_id, MIN(mso.option_id) AS option_id
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN tmp_most_selected_otions mso ON mso.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
;
```

Notes:

- You might need to add some keys for performance.
- If two options has been selected by a user equal times, the one with the least ID will be picked.

Replacing temporary tables in the last statement with the corresponding selects you will get the following query:

```sql
-- get least option-id of most selected options for each user
SELECT u.id AS user_id, MIN(mso.option_id) AS option_id
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN ( -- get otions that were selected most for each user
    SELECT so.user_id, so.option_id
    FROM ( -- get the max number an option was selected for each user
        SELECT so.user_id, MAX(so.numSelected) AS maxSelected
        FROM ( -- get counts for each user and option
            SELECT a.user_id, a.option_id, COUNT(a.option_id) AS numSelected
            FROM answer a
            GROUP BY a.user_id, a.option_id
        ) so
        GROUP BY so.user_id 
    ) ms
    JOIN ( -- get for counts each user and option
        SELECT a.user_id, a.option_id, COUNT(a.option_id) AS numSelected
        FROM answer a
        GROUP BY a.user_id, a.option_id
    ) so
        ON  so.user_id = ms.user_id
        AND so.numSelected = ms.maxSelected
) mso ON mso.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2b20/2

Comment: While the solution is tempting to try, i find this solution bit complicated, check my updated question on how i tried.

Comment: While your updated solution looks fine and seems to work, if you look at [Why is ORDER BY in a FROM Subquery Ignored?](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/), you will see that things can change when you use "undocumented features" like `ORDER BY` in a subselect. In your case it still works because of `LIMIT 1`. But can you be sure that it will work with future versions? I tried to find an answer for this case, with no result yet.