# Get most occured value in the table

Tags: mysql, count

I got following tables

```
1. user
+----+-------------------+
| id | email             |
+----+-------------------+
|  2 | user1@example.com |
|  3 | user2@example.com |
|  1 | user3@example.com |
+----+-------------------+

2. answer
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | question_id | option_id | created             |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 |       2 |           1 |         5 | 2015-12-19 15:15:07 |
|  2 |       2 |           1 |         5 | 2015-12-19 15:16:05 |
|  3 |       2 |           2 |         3 | 2015-12-19 15:16:06 |
|  4 |       2 |           3 |         3 | 2015-12-19 15:16:08 |
|  5 |       2 |           1 |         1 | 2015-12-19 15:32:46 |
|  6 |       2 |           1 |         4 | 2015-12-19 15:39:22 |
|  7 |       2 |           1 |         2 | 2015-12-19 15:39:23 |
|  8 |       2 |           1 |         2 | 2015-12-19 15:40:38 |
|  9 |       2 |           1 |         1 | 2015-12-19 15:41:25 |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

I want to fetch option_id with most occurrences grouped by user with the following condition

1. If there are two or more maximum occurrences of option_id, get last record.

With reference to above answer table, as you see there are four maximum occurrences for `option_id`, in this case i want last in the list to be returned which is `option_id 1`

Here is the query i used to achieve what i want

```
SELECT
    option_id,
    COUNT(option_id) as occurence
FROM
    answer
GROUP BY
    option_id
ORDER BY 
    occurence DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This works, however when i add WHERE condition, it gives me option_id 5, whereas i expect option_id 1

```
SELECT
    option_id,
    COUNT(option_id) as occurence
FROM
    answer
WHERE
    user_id = 2
GROUP BY
    option_id
ORDER BY 
    occurence DESC LIMIT 1;
```

What am i missing here?

Note : This is a follow-up question from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369811/getting-foreign-key-with-maximum-occurences), the reason i am re-posting here is to post simplified version of the same question.

Comment: You order by occurrence. There are four option_ids with the maximum count of 2, so you get one of these. Whether the queries give you ID 1 or 2 or 3 or 5 is a matter of luck, as you don't specify anywhere which you'd prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really only the order_id you are interested in, you can simply add `MAX(created) DESC` to your ORDER BY:

```
SELECT
    option_id,
    COUNT(option_id) as occurence
FROM
    answer
WHERE
    user_id = 2
GROUP BY
    option_id
ORDER BY 
    occurence DESC, MAX(created) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This is what I wanted, although I tried created in order by but missed MAX, let me try this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar on my tables, and that's my solution:

```
SELECT option_id
FROM answer 
WHERE id = (SELECT id
            FROM answer 
            WHERE user_id = 2 
            GROUP BY option_id 
            ORDER BY COUNT(option_id) DESC, id DESC
            LIMIT 1)
```

Or see what happens if you do `ORDER BY occurence DESC, id DESC` in your query.

Comment: No. In your subquery you group by option_id and select arbitrarily one id per option_id (as you don't use an aggregate function such as MIN or MAX on id), e.g. IDs 1,4,5,6,8. You order these records by count and keep the highest, in the example: order = 8,5,4,1,6, keeping ID 8. ID 8 has option_id 2. But desired result is record 9 with option_id 1.

Comment: I've created a table exactly like this and I'm surprised. I'll remember next time to create the most similar circumstances before answering a question. But according to your solution the query returns 'id' 5 not 9, but since only 'option_id' column matters that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: No again. You group by option_id. So for every option_id you get one of the IDs 1/2 + 3/4 + 5/9 + 6 + 7/8. As you sort by `COUNT(option_id) DESC`, ID 6 comes last, because option_id 4 occurs only once. The others get ordered by `id DESC`, so you either have ID 7 or 8 or 9 first (which one depends on which IDs were chosen by the DBMS for the option_ids 2 and 1). Your query results in either option_id 1 or 2 hence, and with a 50% chance that the DBMS picks ID 9 for option_id 1, the chances for both option_ids to be the query result are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Step by step:

1. Count option_id occurrences (group by option_id and count)
2. Get maximum count from above figures (with max or with order by and limit 1)
   3, Get all option_id with this count.
3. Get all records with one of those option_ids.
4. Keep only the last record of the this found records (order by limit 1).

Query:

```
select *
from answer
where option_id in
(
  select option_id
  from answer
  group by option_id
  having count(*) =
  (
    select count(*) as cnt
    from answer
    group by option_id
    order by count(*) desc limit 1
  )
)
order by created desc limit 1;
```